# Compiler doesn't fail when pushing back a std::unique_ptr into a std::vector

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, stdvector, move-semantics

An `unique_ptr` cannot be pushed back into a `std::vector` since it is non-copyable, unless `std::move` is used. However, let `F` be a function that returns a `unique_ptr`, then the operation `std::vector::push_back(F())` is allowed. There is an example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A {
  public:
    int f() { return _f + 10; }

  private:
    int _f = 20;
};

std::unique_ptr<A> create() { return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A); }


int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<A> p1(new A());

  std::vector< std::unique_ptr<A> > v;

  v.push_back(p1); // (1) This fails, should use std::move

  v.push_back(create()); // (2) This doesn't fail, should use std::move?

  return 0;
}
```

**`(2)` is allowed, but `(1)` is not. Is this because the returned value is moved somehow implicitly?**

**In `(2)`, is it actually necessary to use `std::move`?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`std::move(X)` essentially means "here, treat X as if it was a temporary object".

`create()` returns a temporary `std::unique_ptr<A>` to begin with, so `move` is unnecessary.

---

If you want to know more, look into the [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value%20category). Your compiler uses value categories to determine if an expression refers to a temporary object ("rvalue") or not ("lvalue").

`p1` is an lvalue, and `create()` is an rvalue.

Comment: Although true, your answer lacks the part that explains why and how `push_back` allows this behavior which is the part that can help people understand how they can implement and allow such code to work with their own APIs

Answer (score 8):

[`std::vector::push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) has an overload that takes an rvalue reference as input:

```cpp
void push_back( T&& value );
```

The return value of `create()` is an unnamed temporary, ie an rvalue, so it can be passed as-is to `push_back()` without needing to use `std::move()` on it.

`std::move()` is needed only when passing a named variable, ie an lvalue, where an rvalue is expected.

Answer (score 6):

With C++11 we got move constructors and rvalues semantics.

std::move(X) is just a cast to a rvalue which converts X to X&& that is it. Than move ctor takes the job over and move constructors typically "steal" the resources held by the argument. unique_ptr have a move ctor.

Function return values are already a rvalue(unless the function returns an lvalue reference as indicated by @HolyBlackCat in comments) which will trigger the move ctor without needing any extra cast. And since move ctor is defined for unique_ptr it will compile.

Also the reason why  v.push_back(p1);failing is: you try to call copy constructor with an lvalue and it fails because unique_ptr does not have a copy ctor.

Answer (score 2):

It is also worth knowing that it would also work due to compiler ability to move objects that are not move explicitly (NRVO)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A {
  public:
    int f() { return _f + 10; }

  private:
    int _f = 20;
};

std::unique_ptr<A> create() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> x (new A);
    return x; 

}


int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<A> p1(new A());

  std::vector< std::unique_ptr<A> > v;

  //v.push_back(p1); // (1) This fails, should use std::move

  v.push_back(create()); // (2) This doesn't fail, should use std::move?

  return 0;
}
```